# ASP .NET to MySQL: Are persistent connections possible? How?

Tags: asp.net, mysql

Is it possible from ASP .NET through the latest MySQL .NET connector to use persistent connections? I've experimented with this several times, but without any good luck.

How would I go by doing this?

**Edit: By persistent I mean keeping the database connection open, and using only 1 connection for everything.**

Comment: By "persistent", do you mean keeping the database connection open? Or something else?

Comment: Keeping the database connection open, and using only 1 connection for everything. Sorry for not clarifying that. I edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: Why would you do that with a stateless requestor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible. Sounds like you were doing connection pooling. Take a look at

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/12/are-php-persistent-connections-evil/

Forgot to add the link to the mysql docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/apis-php-mysqli.persistconns.html

Comment: Except connection pools inherently close after <expiration criteria> and it doesn't sound like he wants to do that. It almost sounds like he wants to setup intermediate caching, but I'm jumping the gun on that one

Comment: Those are for PHP. I need it for ASP .NET as specified in the post.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-connection-options.html.  Look at the section on connection pooling - particularly the variable connection lifetime and set it to 0 it should effectively act as a persistent connection, ie wait for maximum connection timeout (default is 15 secs I think)

Comment: PS  Before you tweak these parameters I would take a look at how MySQL and the Net/Connector work.  Look at the bottom of the following http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html

Answer (score 2):

This gets asked frequently, and the answer is usually connection pooling is what you are trying to accomplish.  A connection pool is a list of recently opened and unused connections that get reused, shortening the time to setup a brand new connection.  Older connections that don't get used in a certain amount of time get closed. Reference:
[Other Stack Overflow questions and answers regarding connection pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546376/asp-net-to-mysql-are-persistent-connections-possible-how)